# Fourier Transform of Coulomb potential in QFT

Tags: field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, fourier-transform, integration, coulombs-law

I am master student of particle physics and I want to find coulomb  potential $V(r)$ from $\tilde{V}(p)$ in ***Schwartz-Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model*** what I have as $\tilde{V}(p)$  from 16.58 relation:
$$
\tilde{V}(p)= \frac{e_{R}^{2}}{p_{\mu}p^{\mu}}\tag{16.58}
$$
which $e_{R}$ is renormalized charged. What I do to get $V(r)$ is:
$$
V(r)=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{d^{4}p}{(2\pi)^4} e^{ip_{\mu}x^{\mu}}\tilde{V}(p)=\int\frac{ d_{0}p d^3p}{(2\pi)^{4}}e^{ip_{0}t-ipx\cos\theta}\frac{1}{p_{0}^{2}-p^{2}}
$$
and first take $d_{0}p$ on upper contour and:
$$
\int d_{0}p e^{ip_{0}t}\frac{1}{(p_{0}-p)(p_{0}+p)}=i \pi \left(\frac{e^{ipt}}{2p}-\frac{e^{ipt}}{2p} \right) 
$$
so:
$$
V(r)=\int\frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^{4}}e^{-ipx\cos\theta}i \pi \left(\frac{e^{ipt}}{2p}-\frac{e^{ipt}}{2p} \right) 
$$
write $d^{3}p=p^{2}dp d\phi d\cos(\theta)$ we have:
$$
V(r)=\int\frac{p^{2}dp d\phi d\cos(\theta)}{(2\pi)^{4}}e^{-ipx\cos\theta}i \pi \left(\frac{e^{ipt}}{2p}-\frac{e^{ipt}}{2p} \right) 
$$
take $dcos(\theta)$ integral and we got:
$$
\int^{1}_{-1} e^{-ipx\cos(\theta)} d\cos(\theta) = \frac{i}{px}(e^{-ipx}-e^{ipx})
$$
back to integral and finally we got:
$$
V(r)=\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{p^{2}dp}{(2\pi)^{3}}i \pi \left(\frac{e^{ipt}}{2p}-\frac{e^{ipt}}{2p} \right)\frac{i}{px}(e^{-ipx}-e^{ipx})=\frac{1}{16\pi^{2}x}\left(\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} dp e^{ip(x+t)}-\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}dp e^{ip(t-x)} \right)
$$
which is divergent and it is not $V(r)=\frac{-e_{R}^{2}}{4\pi r}$ can someone help me where I make a mistake and show me the way?

Comment: Schwartz covers the Fourier transform of the Coulomb potential in Section 3.4.2

Comment: In the calculation of the contour integral you wrote that the result is zero. This is not the case. One term needs a $-p$.

Comment: You will not find the electrostatic potential with your calculations, but the Green function of the equation $\square A^\mu = j^\mu$. You will have to perform another integration with a point-like source. Also, as Mathphys meister said, be careful with the poles of your integrand.

Answer (score 2):

Beware that you'll need to perform the backwards transformation in 3D Fourier space -- for the photon field $p^2 = 0$, thus your original expression to start from does not make a lot of sense. Apart from that, the classical Coulomb field does not depend on time, which in another hint for the 3D transformation.

In Schwartz's book, this is done in Ch. 3.4.2 (Coulomb potential).

Recapitulating his results:

$$
V(r) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{e_R^2}{p^2} = \int \frac{e^2_R}{(2\pi)^3} e^{-ipr\cos\theta} \sin\theta \, d\theta d\phi dp = \frac{e^2_R}{(2\pi)^2} \frac{1}{ir}\int^\infty_0 dp \frac{e^{ipr}-e^{-ipr}}{p} = \frac{e_R^2}{4\pi r}
$$

where in the last step I've used the known result of the Dirichlet integral:

$$
\int^\infty_0 \frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz = i \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Additional questions related to solving the last $p$ integral: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/356199 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/461414

Comment: thanks for your answer , but this is happen when we cosider one loop correction to photon propagator in chapter 16 and p is not onshell momentum and $ p^2 $  is not zero.